# How does a windows digital licence work?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8

I have a laptop which I bought years ago and that had widows 8 installed, I guess. Then I completely formatted it and installed Linux. Recently though, I formatted it again and installed windows 10. I did that using a bootable usb key which I created using the windows media creation tool.

Now, after the installation, I expected to be asked to insert my product key. But I wasn't. A bit puzzled I then went to the activation tab in my settings and discovered the product was already active thanks to a digital licence.

Am i missing something? What is this licence and where is it? Is it possible that this licence allows me to go from windows 8 to 10 for free? Or maybe is it a demo version which will expire at some point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Microsoft allows to download and use Windows 10 for free.

You can use Media creation tool or download Windows 10 directly from Microsoft's website. Then you can use the bootable media to install Windows 10. In setup, in the screen asking for product key you can click I don't have a product key and skip.

You can continue working forever, though there will be some restrictions. Personalization will be disabled and a nag prompt will show in the desktop corner. Rest will be unaffected.

But windows 7 and 8 activation processes worked differently. When you activated windows for the first time, that hashed value is recorded in the activation database alongside the product key you entered with the installation. Later, when you reinstall the same edition of Windows on the same hardware, with the same product key, it's activated automatically. And, if you tried to use that product key on a different machine (with a different hardware), you'll be denied of doing activation. Thus product keys were tied with the hardware.

But in windows 10 the policy changed. When you upgrade from Windows 7 or Windows 8 or 8.1, the Windows 10 setup checks your current activation status and reports the result to the activation servers. If you're genuine,the Windows activation server generates a Windows 10 license certificate and stores it in with your hashed value and the version you just activated (Home or Pro). Now setup programs can work without product keys.

Answer (score 1):

The license is "bound" to the hardware. If it says active it isn't a "demo license". You can update a laptop to Windows 10 without needing to buy a product key.

Answer (score 0):

The rules change all the time, but I think that you can still fully activate
a Windows 10 installation with a Windows 8 key.

This is done in *Settings > Update & Security > Activation > Update product key*.
If it works, the computer will receive a digital entitlement for Windows 10,
so in future clean installations the activation will be automatic.

If you bought the computer with Windows 8 installed, some OEM vendors burn
the Windows serial key into the BIOS/UEFI where it can be read by the installation
of Windows 10. If that's your case, then your Windows 10 version is already
fully activated.